Is it a good idea to use `std::move` with a function that receives const ref?
Here's a snippet that compiles and works:
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

void print_str(const std::string& str) {
    std::cout << str << '\n';
}

int main() {
    std::string str = "Hello world";
    print_str(std::move(str));
}

Godbolt
As far as I understand, std::move has no effect here.
Two questions:

Is it correct that std::move isn't harmful here, and just has no effect?
Would it be considered good practice to use it anyway? If I don't control print_str, and don't need str after the call, one may say that std::move will have a positive effect if at some point print_str will be changed to get std::string by value.


No it would not be a good practice.
You use std::move to indicate transfer of ownership and that you want to call print_str(std::string&& str). Passing by ref indicates that there should be no transfer of ownership .

Yes, and Yes. You are done with str, and indicate by passing ownership that print_str may consume it if it needs to (and you have to pass ownership explicitly, a compiler can't do it for you in this case, despite it being "obvious"). The fact it doesn't comume it is an implementation detail, and that may change in a day, a month or a year. These semantics are exactly how C++11 remained compatible with all the C++03 code out there.

In C++ it is not a good idea to always do something, even when you don't know why.

@BoP  -  Even more so, when you don't know why.


It's harmful to the readers of this code :) - when someone read code cointaing std::move he thinks  that you want to use move constructor. 2. Why will print_str be changed to get std::string by value?:) It's better to use string_view.


You're correct, move has no effect here, and whether to use this is completely opinion-based.

On one hand, it can indeed improve performance if/when print_str is changed this way. It also expresses intent to not use str again.

On the other hand, it might be a WTF moment for a future reader of your code. Also if you have code after that that (incorrectly) reads from str after the no-op move, if will break when print_str gets updated this way.


Personally, I'd do this only if:

print_str looks like it should take the argument by value but currently doesn't (e.g. a setter that should move the string into the class, but currently copies it)
I'm in a short function where it's hard to accidentally reuse the string after the move.


You say it's opinion-based, but not all opinions have equal merit. Here's the thing: using str after a std:move by mistake is really a non-issue. It's flag-able, both by code review and tooling. WTF for the less-experienced is also a non-argument, because it would prevent 90% of C++'s evolution. We can't keep writing code to the lowest common-denomiator for all eternity.

@StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica   Apparently we can keep writing to the lowest common denominator for eternity - I've just been grappling with some VBA in Excel.

I disagree with "opinion based here". Writing good code is also about experessing intent. If you don't intend to transfer ownership std::move should not be used (even if it is only a typecast)

@PepijnKramer That's one of the points in this answer. You do intend to transfer ownership "if/when print_str is changed [to accept std::string&&]"

@PepijnKramer std::move doesn't always express ownership transfer. In a template, it can very well express "I'm not going to use this object anymore, you can do whatever you want with it" (i.e. "transfer ownership if applicable"). E.g. if you have a template with std::move in it, then instantiate it for an int, you surely wouldn't worry about a useless move. If we're fine with this meaning of move in templates, I think it's not necessarily bad outside of templates too.

Two people disagree with "opinion-based", and root for different opinions. :P

@StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica The WTF factor wouldn't stop me either, but I'd add a short comment explaining why the move is there.

@HolyBlackCat - I'm certain by the time it becomes a hot network question there will ne N people disagreeing and N + 1 opinions :p

Reading the comments, I can agree that it's opinion-based :) BTW I also found that the PVS-Studio static analyzer shows an alert for this kind of std::move (bottom of the page).

@PepijnKramer Ownership-transfer makes 0 sense for std::string to me. Ownership of what? The heap allocated buffer that std::string coincidentially owns, if it exceeds SSO limit? std::move with certain types like string is for performance, plain and simple. Semantic ownership-transfer makes sense for type that conceptually own something, like std::unique_ptr. In a world where performance and memory where no concerns, we would never need std::move for a string. Thus, any discussion about std::move on those types should not be argued with "ownership" IMHO.

@Juliean Even for your optimization case it is still the same thing. The use of std::move as you do it will indeed be a performance optimization. But it is also a transfer of ownership (even if that is not your intent).  The original string is moved from and is now in an unspecified state and is longer responsible for deleting heap allocated buffer so it is still move semantics :)

A slightly related point, which may change the outlook a bit - if you have access to C++17, you should not be using const string& anyway, but string_view:
void print_str(std::string_view str) {
    std::cout << str << '\n';
}

This doesn't fully address your question, though it changes the implications a bit, since we now no longer even have a reference to std::string, but a generic "view" that can map to anything, including string-literals.
It would still be possible for print_str to get an overload taking a forwarding-string, if print_str ever uses an implementation that could make use of move-semantics. I find that rather unlikely though, so for your specific case of print_str, I'd say: This is not likely to ever have a tangible use for moving the input-string, so just use string_view and don't move on the call.
